# Algorithm to compare the Lat lng with a set of database data

Tags: android, performance, algorithm

I am working on a schedule planner android app.

The data is like this:

```
Place
========
lat 
lng 
duration (e.g. 0.5 hour)
isPerferred
```

So I have to get a list of place based on a cirteria eg. given 5 hour, get the set of places.

The problem is , no matter what the preference is , I have to compare the lat lng and get the most nearest place of the latest selected place , but the performance is an concern , are there any apporach to achieve that besides comparing the lat lng one by one? Thanks

```
public double getDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        if (lat1 == lat2 && lon1 == lon2)
            return 0;

        double latA = Math.toRadians(lat1);
        double lonA = Math.toRadians(lon1);
        double latB = Math.toRadians(lat2);
        double lonB = Math.toRadians(lon2);
        double cosAng = (Math.cos(latA) * Math.cos(latB) * Math.cos(lonB-lonA)) +
                    (Math.sin(latA) * Math.sin(latB));
        double ang = Math.acos(cosAng);
        double dist = ang *6371;
        return dist;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** 
[Location.distanceBetween](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29) does exactly what you need:

```
distanceBetween (double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results)
```

Comment: Thanks , that is still doing computation one by one?

Comment: I think we can assume it is optimized, but you can do a quick test against your own implementation